# rectangle wont show up on wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

The rectangle won't show up for me on a windows computer. I gave this to someone else who was a mac user and the rectangle showed up. I am not receiving any errors so I can't seem to figure this out. I am using python 2.7.7.

```
import socket
import wx

class WindowFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title, size=(500, 400))
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour("#E6E6E6")
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE, size =(410, 28), pos=(0,329))

        sendbutton=wx.Button(self.panel, label ="Send", pos =(414,325), size=(65,35))
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()


    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('#d4d4d4'))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#c56c00'))
        dc.DrawRectangle(10, 15, 90, 60)
        self.Show(True)
if __name__=="__main__": 
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = WindowFrame(None, 'ChatClient')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [wxpython won't draw rectangle on panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370218/wxpython-wont-draw-rectangle-on-panel)

Comment: @MikeDriscoll, That threw me too, but OP is asking a different question here (not sure if it should actually be a different post)

Comment: Yeah, you might be right. I retracted. Anyway, the answer to this one was a parenting issue...the OP is trying to draw to the frame instead of the panel.

Comment: My bad. Its just that making this project successful would be great to me since this is my first official project since I learned python. I keep checking the post from before that I made but I wasn't getting answers fast enough so I made this.

Comment: I had a similar problem.  I was modifying a program that showed lines on a frame and I wanted to put them on a panel instead.  It looked okay, but as soon as I set a panel background color, I didn't see my lines any more.  It was because I was calling the Frame's OnPaint, and as long as the panel had nothing to do in its OnPaint I could see the lines.  But just adding the background color to the panel was enough for it to cover my lines!  When I did the proper binding and used the proper dc, everything worked as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this code is that the OP is wanting to draw on the panel, but then proceeds to tell the PaintDC object to paint to the frame. The OnPaint method should look like this:

```
def OnPaint(self, event):
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)  # <<< This was changed
    dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('#d4d4d4'))
    dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#c56c00'))
    dc.DrawRectangle(10, 15, 90, 60)
```